# Showing the roots of an irreducible cubic polynomial can't have equal absolute value

Tags: elementary-number-theory, galois-theory

Say I have an irreducible cubic polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$, $f(X)=X^3 - AX^2 - BX -C$ with integer coefficients and such that $f(X)=(X-a_1)(X-a_2)(X-a_3)$ where the $a_i\in\mathbb{C}$ such that none of the ratios $a_i/a_j$ are roots of unity for $i\neq j$. I want to prove that $|a_1|=|a_2|=|a_3|$ cannot hold.

What I did:

I see that one of the roots has to be real, say $a_1$. Then if the other two are real this is easy to see that we get a contradiction. However, I'm stuck on the second case when $a_2,a_3$ are complex. If we assume $|a_1|=|a_2|=|a_3|$, we know that $|C|=|a_1||a_2||a_3|=|a_1|^3$ so since $a_1$ is real it must be a cube root of $\pm C$. From here I'm stuck. I got a hint saying I can use Galois theory to show the other two are also cube roots of $\pm C$, but I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: In the title, you ask whether the roots *may* not have the same magnitude, but in the question, you ask if the roots *must* not have the same magnitude.  Which is it?

Comment: @XanderHenderson I meant that they must not have the same magnitude, under the assumption that their ratios are not roots of unity, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "a root of unity"?

Comment: What is the source of this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $a_1$ and $C$ are real, from $|C| = |a_1|^3$ we have $a_1^3 = \pm C$ for some choice of sign. So $a_1$ is a root of $g(X) = X^3 \mp C$ for some choice of sign.  You told us $a_1$ has the cubic minimal polynomial $f(X)$. Compare these polynomials.  There is no need to use "Galois theory" (Galois groups), just use properties of minimal polynomials. There is no need to break up your argument into cases the way you did: handle all possibilities with a single argument.

The reasoning is not specific to degree $3$: it works with irreducible $f(X)$ in $\mathbf Q[X]$ havng odd degree bigger than $1$.  The story is different in even degree: all roots of $X^4 + 3X^3 + 7X^2 + 9X + 9$ have absolute value $\sqrt{3}$ and all roots of $X^6 - 4X^5 + 9X^4 - 15X^3 + 18X^2 - 16X + 8$ have absolute value $\sqrt{2}$; see Examples 4.5 and 4.6 [here](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/galoistheory/numbersoncircle.pdf).

The way you broke up your work into two cases reminds me of a funny story, when someone described to me his attempt to prove the division algorithm in $\mathbf Z$ (for $a, b$ in $\mathbf Z$ with $b \not= 0$ there are unique $q$ and $r$ in $\mathbf Z$ such that $a = bq+r$ and $0 \leq r < |b|$).  He told me he was "halfway done" and I asked what that meant. He said he had treated the case when $b \mid a$ and now he was looking at the other case where $b \nmid a$. So he considered his 1st case to be "half" of his solution.

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't even think to look at the fact that $f$ is the minimal polynomial, which clearly solves the problem. Regarding the splitting of the cases, I thought I could somehow manipulate the equations to get somewhere like in the real case, but it doesn't always help.